# Injecting test classes created by Platform Launcher

Tags: junit5

I'm running JUnit 5 tests programmatically (Kotlin):

```
LauncherFactory.create().execute(
        LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder
                .request()
                .selectors(
                        DiscoverySelectors.selectClass(Sometest::class.java)
                )
                .build(),
        SummaryGeneratingListener()
)
```

Is there any way to hook into the Launcher's lifecycle to inject test classes with something before the tests are run?

I'm trying to use `@ExtendWith`, but then my `TestInstancePostProcessor` is still created by JUnit, whereas I need a link to my original scope, from where I execute the `Launcher`.

Comment: There's no API to supply an instance of `TestInstancePostProcessor` from Jupiter in a Platform launcher scope.
The missing link can be circumvented by using a static field, a system property, JNDI or some other common exchange mechanism. See this example: https://gist.github.com/sormuras/2e9aeaebc0f272c3b39394d314531e1a

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/506 - Introduce mechanism for programmatic extension management

Comment: @Sormuras I'm doing workaround via static fields which is really bad, but it works for now. Thanks for the link, hopefully JUnit devs will fix it.

Comment: What your use-case in detail, Yuri? Why do you need to instantiate the injector already at the scope where you build the launcher request?

Comment: @Sormuras everything I need to inject exists only within the scope of the program entry point, i.e. main() function.